# Netsuite - Automating SKU Substitution

Tags: erp

I'm having an issue where I need to automate sku substitution methodology in the following scenario:

- In the future we will have two versions of a sku (one saleable in the US only, sku A and another saleable in international markets and in the US, sku B)
- I want to build sku substitution methodology such that when A inventory is completely deleted B is automatically replaced on the sales order

Currently I have activated the sku substitution as it exists in netsuite today. Through talking with their support team this substitution cannot be handled automatically - it can only be done manually through the UI.

Has anyone achieved automating this? The bulk of our orders are fed in automatically via integration with our website and through EDI with our larger retailers. Therefore it is cumbersome to go into every order and perform sku substitution under these parameters.

I'm also happy to implement suitescripting etc but am not sure where to start or if there a better ways than writing more scripts.

Thanks